# How to create virtual host with xampp VM?

Tags: apache, xampp, virtual-machine, xampp-vm

I recently started use xampp vm ! I want to connect my project exist in `/Users/mine/project` . So I tried with vhost from `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` ,that is open by xampp application volumes tab `Explore`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/mine/project"
    ServerName mine.online
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I update `hosts` file from terminal like below,

```
192.168.64.2    mine.online //192.168.6.2 is xampp vm ip
```

Also I do uncomment in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Finally I restarted my apache ! But it show me 404 not found . Please help me how to run correctly ?

> Plus => is there any way to clone git project to xampp vm 's htdocs folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this XAMPP-VM setup. But it looks like the linux machine hosting lamp, cannot access local (your physical machine) datas. So */Users/mine/project* is out of scope. It looks like you cannot add a new mounted folder.

At the moment there is only a mounted folder for the /opt/lampp accessible from your host. This folder include your root web folder so you can store the files and add a new VirtualHost with this path .. /opt/lampp/../your-amazing-project/public..

I **think** that this particular setup (with those file paths) cannot be done with XAMPP-VM. But I'm not sure.

You can look on projets like [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet) if you want to serve and develop PHP projets in /Users/..

There are recommended for PHP projects with Laravel PHP framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your hosts file as you would do in previous versions of Xampp.

```
127.0.0.1   mine.online
```

Then from Xampp's application open network tab and enable forwarding localhost:8080 to port 80. It should look like this:

```
localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH)
```

Now when you open `mine.online:8080` it should work

For your additional question, yes you can clone git project to htdocs folder however writing operations in vm is extremely slow. I found out that committing/pushing through Source Tree is extremely slow as well.

Answer (score 1):

-->Open your local terminal and run "vi /etc/hosts" without quote

-->Add "192.168.64.2 mine.online" line without quote and then save the file

-->Go to Xampp and start the xampp.

-->Go to volumes tab and mount the "/opt/lampp" volume.

-->Press the explore button and then go to "lampp/etc/extra"

-->Open the "httpd-vhosts.conf" file and edit like as the given one

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mine.online
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER"
    ServerName mine.online
    ServerAlias www.mine.online
    ErrorLog "logs/mine.online-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/mine.online-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

-->Then go to "/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf"

-->Uncomment "Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

-->Restart the services from Xampp

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

01) first try to ping to your host to make sure vhost is working (success  response on the server ).

```
ping mine.online
```

02) Also can you try editing your vhost file as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mine.online
ServerName mine.online
ServerAlias mine.online
DocumentRoot /Users/mine/project
</VirtualHost>
```

If this is Ubuntu server try to add permissions for project folder:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /Users/mine/project
sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/mine/project
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```